# make Yajl iOS framework file

Tags: ios, yajl

i want to make the "YAJLiOS.framework" file from code getted from github:https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc

There is one who tells me how to make it?
because i tried by building the "Project-iOS" but there is no file made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

open a Terminal window and change inside the yajl-objc directory you got from github.
There you type:

```
cd Project-iOS
make
```

In the directory "Project-iOS" a "build" directory will be created where you'll find your "YAJLiOS.framework".